# Dispatched and re-rendered callback?

Tags: reactjs, redux

It's easiest to explain what I'm trying to accomplish with an example:

```
addContact = ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.props.setField('contacts', contacts => update(contacts, {$push: [{name: 'NEW_CONTACT'}]}));
    this.props.setFocus(`contacts.${this.props.data.contacts.length-1}.name`);
};
```

In this example, `this.props.setField` dispatches an action which causes an extra field to be added to my form.

`this.props.setFocus` then attempts to focus this new field.

This won't work because the form hasn't re-rendered yet when `setFocus` is called.

Is there any way to get a callback for when my component has been re-rendered after a `dispatch` call?

---

If you need to see it, `setField` looks like this:

```
setField(name, value) {
    if(_.isFunction(value)) {
        let prevValue = _.get(data, name);
        if(prevValue === undefined) {
            let field = form.fields.get(name);
            if(field) {
                prevValue = field.props.defaultValue;
            }
        }
        value = value(prevValue);
    }
    dispatch(actions.change(form.id, name, value));
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I would put

```
this.props.setFocus(`contacts.${this.props.data.contacts.length-1}.name`);
```

in `componentDidUpdate` and I would call it on some condition. Like let's say, `prevProps.data.contact.length < this.props.data.contacts`.

**UPDATE**

You should keep this:

```
addContact = ev => {
   ev.preventDefault();
   this.props.setField('contacts', contacts => update(contacts, {$push: [{name: 'NEW_CONTACT'}]}));
};
```

In a parent component, and in that component you will render all the sub components:

```
render() {
   return {
      <div>
         {contacts.map(c => <ContactComponent key='blah' contact={c}>)}
         <a onClick={addContact}>Add Contact</a>
      </div>
   };
}
```

Then your contact component, will be as you like, the same goes for all the other elements you want to accommodate with this functionality.

At that point, you're asking:

> Where is the focus thingy?

What you need for this abstraction-ish is higher order composition. I will give you an example, but please make time to read about HOCs.

**This will be you HOC:**

```
function withAutoFocusOnCreation(WrappedComponent) {
  // ...and returns another component...
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      // contacts string below can be changed to be handled dynamically according to the wrappedComponent's type
      // just keep in mind you have access to all the props of the wrapped component
      this.props.setFocus(`contacts.${this.props.data.contacts.length-1}.name`);
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

And then in each child component you can use it as a decorator or just call it with your HOC and that's all. I won't write more, but do make the time to read more about HOCs, here is the official documentation's page
[official documentation's page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html). But you can check Dan Abramov's video on egghead as well. I hope my answer helps you, please accept it if it does :) Take care!

Comment: I could do that, sure, but I'm looking for a more general solution that I could put into a library.

Comment: You mean that you need it to be reusable to other components for example?

Comment: Yes, but not specifically "contacts". `setField` and `setFocus` are part of my lib -- I want to make it easy to focus a field after creating it.

Comment: Oh then that changes everything. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm familiar with HOCs -- `setFocus` *comes* from a HOC. I suppose I could defer the focus with a [lifecycle](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle) hook, but then I'd still need to set some intermediary state to trigger it, which is what I'm trying to avoid.